# How to right align text in Dash Input Select component with CSS-style?

Tags: css, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to right align the text in [Dash Bootstrap Input Select component](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/input/).
Adding CSS-style: text-align; right does not work (see below):

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

select = dbc.Select(
    id="select",
    options=[
        {"label": "Option 1", "value": "1"},
        {"label": "Option 2", "value": "2"},
    ],
    style={
        'text-align': 'right',
           }

)
```

returning (with text aligned to the left as default). What am I missing?:
[image]

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to align the text to the right when I select an option. I'm running this with ```dash==2.1.0``` and visualized it using FireFox.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Based on own limited testing it seems to work on windows-machines. But on apple products (imac og iphone) it does not work. I have no idea why that might be.

Comment: I ran the code using a Macbook

Comment: `style={'text-align': 'right'}` works for me with Dash 2.3.1 and dash-bootstrap-components 1.0.2, using Bootstrap 5 